# Responsive carousel using breakpoints

Tags: javascript, slick.js

If im using something like this with breakpoints, is it possible to set a rule between say 200 and 320? So that everything between 200 and 300 would be affected like with media queries.

```
$('.responsive').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }

  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.innerWidth` to get the width on resize, then just wrap a few if statements around it to set your mins and max:

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
if((w > 200)||(w <300)) { do something }
```

then you can use

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    myChangeFunction();
};
```

hope this helps

Comment: See im sure that works great but i have next to no experience with js so what you just wrote could be chinese lol. im not sure what to do with it. could you elaborate a bit?